# Android SOAP response cut off

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I have recently started having some issues working with kSOAP2 with Android, specifically when receiving the response. Here's the problem, tested with multiple AVDs and a physical device:

I start sending a request to my web service, which is running on my local computer, and normally get the following exception when receiving the response..

```
01-15 17:15:43.819: E/SOAP(2904): java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() is not available. Is this a reentrant call?
```

What bothers me the most is that at first it would always happen, but now it only occurs if I send the request via my physical device (now the AVDs get a proper response).

Also, at the beginning I decided to inspect the traffic, to check whether I was receiving a response with a correct format, but I saw that the SOAP response was simply cut off at some point (inside a node).

I found the commit that introduced this exception in the library, and well, as you can see it is launched when the response is null (or having errors, I guess): http://gitorious.org/ginger/libcore/commit/c6dae581716b9362a5c7f166c80a7f2b46ed1124/diffs?diffmode=sidebyside&fragment=1

Any ideas? :)

**EDIT:** I'm attaching the code where the call is made:

```
ListRQ rq = new ListRQ(c, l, s, "");

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("request");
    pi.setValue(rq);
    pi.setType(rq.getClass());
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    envelope.addMapping(Params.NAMESPACE, "ListRQ", ListRQ.class);
    MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
    md.register(envelope);

    HttpTransportSE htse = new HttpTransportSE(Params.URL);
    htse.debug = true;

    try {
        htse.call(Params.GetList.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        Log.d("SOAP", response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("SOAP", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: i'm not sure you are supposed to call getInputStream() several times

Comment: We would need to see your code to offer more suggestions, but as @njzk2 says, you might be calling `getInputStream()` twice on the same connection.  Perhaps from separate threads, perhaps not.